# JADE in NodeJS Tech Stack

Tags: node.js, pug

I am working on a POC on Node JS, and I learnt that a typical tech stack will look like - Jade (instead of HTML)/ NodeJS/ and some database. My question instead of Jade can we use HTML 5? This is to avoid learning one more language to complete the POC. Also I assume that I will be able to expose the Node JS methods as rest API instead of having PHP or Java layer.

More over if I use simple HTMl/JQuery  - for UI and Node.js ( for restful service) it will be easy for one to migrate to other framework easily. Please share your experience.

Comment: `My question instead of Jade can we use HTML 5?` YES!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more an opinionated question, so i would like to share my opinion.

> My question instead of Jade can we use HTML 5?

Jade is not alternative of HTML5. Jade is a templating engine whereas HTML5 is not. So, both are different.
Getting back to your question, you can use HTML5 as well.

> Role of Jade

**Ex:** Consider yourself in a scenario where after user login you need to display a profile page and in profile page You need to print 'Hello '.
Since  is dynamic value, so it can't be hardcoded in HTML file. Therefore, you place a placeholder in HTML (since you have added placeholder and made your HTML file generic for all user, thats why such file is called template file instead of plain HTML file). Now you can fill the placeholder with dynamic value either on server side or on browser.

1. If you select to replace placeholder by their value on server side, you use some templating engines. Ex EJS, JADE etc. Templating engine are responsible for generating HTML from template
2. If you select to replace placeholder by their value on client side, then you can choose to opt `Ajax calls` and fill your placeholder using Jquery or Angular.js may be handy if your project is expected to be big enough.

> if I use simple HTMl/JQuery - for UI and Node.js ( for restful service) it will be easy for one to migrate to other framework easily.

IMO, using HTML with jquery for UI is better, since it is simple and traditional and you will get more support on community forum. Also, you wont have to learn template, templating engines straightaway.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed response

Comment: @vinSan glad it helped!! :) You can accept the answer if it answers your question or if you need some more info relevant to this question, update your question so that we can respond to it.